# Como abrir una activity cuando llega un push en Backgroud

Tags: android, android-studio, android-intent

Quiero consultar, como hacer que se abra la activity notificaciones.class cuando llegue un mensaje push con la aplicacion en background.

tengo una main.class que es mi main principal y launcher en el manifest.
y una notificaciones.class que se abre para las notificaciones.

*Cuando la aplicacion esta en *Foreground* y llega el mensaje push, al dar click en el push pasa automaticamente de main.class hacia notificaciones.class y **es justo lo que quiero**.

*Pero cuando la aplicacion esta en *Background* y llega el mensaje push, al dar click en el push se va hacia el main.class **(como hago para que en vez del main.class vaya hacia notificaciones.class)**

Gracias de antemano...
Aqui les dejo el codigo del firebaseservice:

```js
public class MiFirebaseMessaginService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

    public static  final String TAG ="NOTICIAS";

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);

        String from = remoteMessage.getFrom();
        Log.d(TAG, "Mensaje recibido de:" + from);

        if (remoteMessage.getNotification() !=null){
            Log.d(TAG, "Notificacion:" + remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());

            mostrarNotificacion(remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle(),remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());

        }

        if (remoteMessage.getData().size()> 0){

            Log.d(TAG, "Data:" + remoteMessage.getData());
        }

    }

    private void mostrarNotificacion(String title, String body) {

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, Notificaciones.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);


        Uri defaultSoundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);


        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder= (NotificationCompat.Builder) new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notifications_active_black_24dp)
                .setContentTitle(title)
                .setContentText(body)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
                .setVisibility(android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

        NotificationManager notificationManager =
                (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        notificationManager.notify(0, notificationBuilder.build());
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

He encontrado un ejemplo espero que te sirve de utilidad, usa el notication.flag 
[Notificación  solución](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13716784/7332139)